# How to notify C# code from Azure database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, azure

I am creating a WCF service (CALLER) for Azure. The service(CALLER) calls async methods of another third party service(EXTN). The third party service calls the callback methods of another WCF service (LISTNER) hosted by me on Azure. CALLER enter the service details in the databsae with status = PENDING.

In the callback service (LISTENER) I am updating the status of the request as COMPLETED/FAILED in the database.

I want to notify my C# code after the value is database changed by LISTENER.

Is it possible????

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this with Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx) [MS DevLabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)